# MYSQL Order By List

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have table A which have an 'ID' and 'Message' and another table B which is ordered. I wish to order table A according to how they are ordered in table B.

Example - Table A:

```
ID    Message
-------------
1     ABC
2     DEF
3     HIJ
4     KLM
5     NOP
```

Table B:

```
ID
---
5
2
4
1
3
```

Expected Result:

```
ID    Message
-------------    
5     NOP
2     DEF
4     KLM
1     ABC
3     HIJ
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.message, s.stream_id
FROM Stream s
ORDER BY ..... ;
```

How can I do it?
Apparently using FIND_IN_SET doesn't take into consideration the order of Table B

UPDATE

Table B is getting ordered as follows:

```
SELECT stream_id 
FROM SearchCache 
GROUP BY stream_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(stream_id);
```

Therefore, the query should be something as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.message, s.stream_id
FROM Stream s
ORDER BY s.stream_id *SOMETHING* (SELECT stream_id 
                                  FROM SearchCache 
                                  GROUP BY stream_id 
                                  ORDER BY COUNT(stream_id)) ASC;
```

Comment: How is `Table B` ordered? It does not appear to have any particular order, and you cannot reliably retrieve rows in the order they were inserted...

Comment: How did you specify the order when selecting from Table B? If you didn't specify an ORDER BY for Table B, then the answer is that you cannot reliably determine what order the rows will come out without specifying an ORDER BY.

Comment: @Travesty3 Great minds alike, eh?

Comment: Do you have primary key on tableb?

Comment: So `Table B` is the result of an `INSERT INTO SELECT` or just a query?

Comment: @cgval I get it I think - answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are ordering `Table B` by the aggregate `COUNT()`, you can use that same value in your `ORDER BY`. Just add it to the `SELECT` list which derives `Table B`.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT 
  s.message, 
  s.stream_id
FROM 
  Stream s
  /* Join against a subquery that produces a count per stream_id */
  /* Using LEFT JOIN in case none exist for a given s.stream_id */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT stream_id, COUNT(*) AS num_streams
    FROM SearchCache
    GROUP BY stream_id
   ) stream_counts ON s.stream_id = stream_counts.stream_id
/* Order by the COUNT() aggregate supplied by the joined subquery */
ORDER BY stream_counts.num_streams ASC
```

Note: *if you post a sample of the `SearchCache` table, I'll update with a SQLFiddle example...*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.message 
FROM tablea a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT (@auto:=@auto+1) auto, id 
            FROM tableb, (SELECT @auto:=0) AS a) AS b ON a.id = b.id 
ORDER BY b.auto;
```